# Orthogonal projection of vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Find the orthogonal projection of vector $b$ onto column space of given matrix $A$, then find orthogonal projection of the same vector onto kernel of matrix $A^T$.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$b=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Ok i know what is column space, it is simply image of $A$ wich is obviosely span of columns of $A$ since they are linearly independent, now, when it comes to orthogonal projections, all i know is that $proj_\vec{a}\vec{b}=\frac{\vec{a}\vec{b}}{||\vec{a}||}\vec{a}$. Is this the same formula that i can use here? Because even if it is, how could i calculate dot product of $b$ and column space?

Comment: Your formula for projection requires that $\vec a$ be a unit vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you mentioned is about projections on vectors. The problem here is about projections on spaces.

Determine an orthogonal basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of the space spanned by the collumns, using Gram-Schmidt. Then the projection of $b$ is $\langle b,e_1\rangle e_1+\langle b,e_2\rangle e_2$.

Comment: Ok i used Gram-Schmidt and i had ${e_1, e_2} $=$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ , $\frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 8 \\ 4 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} $. I checked their orthogonality after i found them and they are orthogonal. Now i only need to find projection of b with your formula, right?

Comment: @cdummie Their norms should be equal to $1$.

Comment: So now i need to find a norm for both vectors, i'll do that now and respond immediately!

Comment: Ok i thik i found out norm of $e_1$ is square root of 3 and of $e_2$ is $\sqrt{105}$ over 3, then $b^Te_1=0$ and $b^Te_2=\frac{\sqrt{105}}{3}$ so $b= 0e_1 + \frac{\sqrt{105}}{3} e_2$. Is that right?

Comment: @cdummie That's not what I got. I mean, I got the same $e_1$, but$$e_2=\frac13\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Well i used gram schmidt and got vector $e_2=\frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 8 \\ 4 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$ but when i found it's norm it was $e_2=\frac{\sqrt{105}}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 8 \\ 4 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$, and that's how i ended up with my solution, i checked again and $e_1$ and $e_2$ are orthogonal, orthogonal basis isn't unique right, there's a chance that we can get two different correct solutions, right?

Comment: @cdummie Your vector $e_2$ does not belong to the space spanned by the columns.

Comment: I did gram schmidt again and got the same result, why my calculation gives me vector that is out of space spanned by the columns when i used base of  column space to find orthogonal vectors, i mean i started with first and second column in my gram schmidt process, how i ended up with vector that isn't even in span of columns of A?

Comment: @cdummie Since I didn't see your computations, I cannot answer that. What I know is this: If $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the first and the second columns respectively, then my $e_1$ is your $e_1$. Then I define $v_2=u_2-\langle u_2,e_1\rangle e_1$ and I get$$v_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$Finally, I define $e_2=\frac{v_2}{\|v_2\|}$. SInce $\|v_2\|=3$…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66763/discussion-between-cdummie-and-jose-carlos-santos).